# Можно ли из списка списков получить словарь с объединением значений на основании совпадения ключа?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, словари, dict

Можно ли из такой структуры:

```
a = [
  [1, [2, 3]],
  [2, [1, 3]], 
  [3, [1, 2]], 
  [1, [5, 6]]
]
```

получить словарь следующего вида: `{1: [2, 3, 5, 6], 2: [1, 3], 3: [1, 2]}`?

Пробовал через обычный `dict()`, но тогда, если ключ уже существует, то берется его последнее значение и получается `{1: [5, 6], 2: [1, 3], 3: [1, 2]}`.

Comment: Возник дополнительный вопрос - а какой из предложенных методов наиболее выгоден с точки зрения занимаемой памяти и быстродействия? Потому что во всех случаях создается новая переменная, в которую и будет записан этот словарь. Изменить существующую переменную подходящим образом уже нельзя?

Comment: Внесите дополнительный вопрос в основной. вы можете его редактировать.

Comment: @strawdog Спасибо, внес.

Comment: @Сергей@strawdog нет, надо задать новый вопрос, а не изменять старый, 3 участника не должны отслеживать вопрос и обновлять ответы по мере появления новых вопросов, тем более когда один из ответов был принят

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in a:
    d[k].extend(v)
```

Answer (score 4):

Вот так вот:

```py
a = [
    [1, [2, 3]],
    [2, [1, 3]], 
    [3, [1, 2]], 
    [1, [5, 6]]
]
    
d = {}
    
for k, v in a:
    d.setdefault(k, []).extend(v)
    
print(d)
```

Answer (score 2):

Чуть более сложный вариант, но зато он позоляет получить любые структуры в результате - кортежи, вложенные списки и т.д.:

```py
from itertools import groupby
    
res = {
    a: sum([x[1] for x in b], []) 
    for a,b in groupby(
        sorted(a), 
        key=lambda x: x[0]
    )
}
```

---

результат:

```
In [46]: res
Out[46]: {1: [2, 3, 5, 6], 2: [1, 3], 3: [1, 2]}
```